# xero PHP variable which starts with {

Tags: php, xero-api

A number of Xero accounts API samples have PHP variables which start with `{`

Example:

```
$invoices = {invoices:[{type: Invoice.TypeEnum.ACCREC, contact:{contactID:"00000000-0000-0000-000-000000000000"}, lineItems:[{ description:"Acme Tires", quantity:2.0, unitAmount:20.0, accountCode:"000", taxType:"NONE", lineAmount:40.0}], date:"2019-03-11", dueDate:"2018-12-10", reference:"Website Design", status: Invoice.StatusEnum.DRAFT}]};
```

I am struggling to understand how this can work. I am trying to use the API to create multiple invoices in the same call, I can do it fine in Postman so I know my code is OK.

I have tried following:

- [creating-an-invoice-using-oauth2-in-xero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59149006/creating-an-invoice-using-oauth2-in-xero)
- [Using the documents](https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-oauth2/blob/master/docs/accounting/Api/AccountingApi.md#createinvoices)

But for some reason I just can't find a way to make it work.

Comment: @NigelRen Naah it's not in JSON format I guess

Comment: Thanks, I had tried json_decode but it appears to be the creation of the variable which fails

Comment: It looks more like a Javascript object as no quotes round the field names etc. to make proper JSON.

Comment: Looks a bit like someone typed the documentation “free hand”, without actually testing the code? Does it work, if you _make_ this a valid JSON _string_ in that place? `$invoices = '{"invoices":[{"type":"Invoice.TypeEnum.ACCREC","contact":{"contactID":"00000000-0000-0000-000-000000000000"},"lineItems":[{"description":"Acme Tires","quantity":2,"unitAmount":20,"accountCode":"000","taxType":"NONE","lineAmount":40}],"date":"2019-03-11","dueDate":"2018-12-10","reference":"Website Design","status":"Invoice.StatusEnum.DRAFT"}]}';`

Comment: Yes it does, for some reason when I use the full variable value (about 30 times the size of the sample) json_decode doesn't work, I'll need to have a look at maximum size.

Answer (score 0):

All our SDKs and documentation is generated from our OpenAPI specs.  Generating runnable code in our docs is our long term goal.  In the interim, we needed to offer "some" generated docs, but the JSON payloads are not meant to be used.

We have created a sample app that demonstrates different endpoints and displays the code used to make the call.

https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-oauth2-app

Here is the code you'll need to create an invoices

```
$result = $apiInstance->getContacts($xeroTenantId);
$contactId = $result->getContacts()[0]->getContactId();

$contact = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Contact;
$contact->setContactId($contactId);

$arr_invoices = []; 

$invoice_1 = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice;
$invoice_1->setReference('Ref-456')
    ->setDueDate(new DateTime('2019-12-10'))
    ->setContact($contact)
    ->setLineItems($lineitems)
    ->setStatus(XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice::STATUS_AUTHORISED)
    ->setType(XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice::TYPE_ACCPAY)
    ->setLineAmountTypes(\XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\LineAmountTypes::EXCLUSIVE);    
array_push($arr_invoices, $invoice_1);

$invoice_2 = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice;
$invoice_2->setReference('Ref-123')
    ->setDueDate(new DateTime('2019-12-02'))
    ->setContact($contact)
    ->setLineItems($lineitems)
    ->setStatus(XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice::STATUS_AUTHORISED)
    ->setType(XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice::TYPE_ACCPAY)
    ->setLineAmountTypes(\XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\LineAmountTypes::EXCLUSIVE);    
array_push($arr_invoices, $invoice_2);

$invoices = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoices;
$invoices->setInvoices($arr_invoices);

$result = $apiInstance->createInvoices($xeroTenantId,$invoices);
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it working, I'm now looking at how I can run it monthly using a Cron job below the www directory so that it's not accessible via the web. I currently use 2 API's to create pdf invoices and email them and create an audit file to import into Sage, if I get this working I'll change to  Xero. Essencially I'm replacing the invoice creation and emailing with Xero after the  API's have been called for the invoice details.

Comment: The code above actually creates "bills" from suppliers, change "TYPE_ACCPAY" to "TYPE_ACCREC" in example.php if you want to create customer invoices.